react-quill custom image upload not working
Problem
enter image description here
As in the attached picture, after the image file upload API call is completed(imageHandler code),
the image URL is not added to the editor, but added in base64 format.
I think imageHandler code is not running.
nextjs, react environment.
Code
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { fetchUploadImage } from '../../../api/image';

const ReactQuill = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const { default: RQ } = await import('react-quill');
    const { default: ImageResize } = await import('quill-image-resize');
    const { default: ImageCompress } = await import('quill-image-compress');
    RQ.Quill.register('modules/imageCompress', ImageCompress);
    RQ.Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

    return function forwardRef({ forwardedRef, ...props }) {
      const newProps = {
        ...props,
        modules: {
          ...props.modules,
          imageResize: {
            parchment: RQ.Quill.import('parchment'),
            modules: ['Resize', 'DisplaySize', 'Toolbar'],
          },
          imageCompress: {
            quality: 0.9,
            debug: true,
            suppressErrorLogging: false,
            insertIntoEditor: undefined,
          },
        },
      };
      return <RQ ref={forwardedRef} {...newProps} />;
    };
  },
  { ssr: false, loading: () => <div>Loading...</div> }
);

const uploadImage = async (blob: FormData) => {
  if (blob === null) return '';

  const data = await fetchUploadImage({
    body: blob,
  });

  if (data.message) alert(data.message);
  if (data.file_url) return data.file_url;
  return '';
};

const Editor = ({
  description,
  setDescription,
}: {
  description: string;
  setDescription: Dispatch<SetStateAction<FormData | null>>;
}) => {
  const quillRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    input.click();

    input.addEventListener('change', async () => {
      try {
        const file = input.files?.[0];
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('images', file, file.name);
        const imageURL = await uploadImage(formData);
        const range = quillRef.current.getEditorSelection();
        quillRef.current
          .getEditor()
          .insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', imageURL);
        quillRef.current.getEditor().setSelection(range.index + 1);
        document.body.querySelector(':scope > input').remove();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  };

  const modules = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, 3, false] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
          ['blockquote'],
          [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
          [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
          [{ align: [] }, 'link', 'image'],
        ],
        handlers: {
          image: imageHandler,
          bold: () => {
            alert('custom bold');
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="form__content">
      <ReactQuill
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '500px', paddingTop: '10px' }}
        theme="snow"
        forwardedRef={quillRef}
        value={description}
        onChange={setDescription}
        modules={modules}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editor;

My Full Code Link: https://gist.github.com/OlimNoaah/eef25e8765397c00f1cd3abd1514f909
ENV
    "quill-image-compress": "^1.2.32",
    "quill-image-resize": "^3.0.9",
    "quill-image-resize-module-react": "^3.0.0",


Please copy/paste the console output instead of providing a screenshot or link to image.
